# How to iterate object in freemarker template?

Tags: java, freemarker

I have next data view and problem to iterate and show eaach nested object in html template.

so this is how I can display each of the form views (todayFilled etc )in the desired html block?

```
<#assign data>
{

        todayFilledForms:{
            title: 'Today filled forms',
            logo:'fas fa-chart-bar',
            type: "bg-gradient-danger",
     
        },
        allFilledForms:{
            title: 'All filled forms',
            logo:'fas fa-chart-bar',
            type: "bg-gradient-info",
       
        },
        monthFilledForms:{
         title: 'Month filled forms',
         logo:'fas fa-chart-bar',
         type: "bg-gradient-success",
     
        },
        numberUsersSystem:{
           title: 'Number of users in the system',
           logo:'fas fa-user-plus',
           type: "bg-gradient-warning",
       
        }
}
```

<#list products as data>
???
</#list>

How can I iterate it and show html template for each type of form (todayFilledForms, allFilledForms etc)

Answer (score -1):

The list iteration syntax is like `<#list listName as variable>logic to read something </#list>` so as per that logic can you try your code as `<#list data as entry>${entry}</#list>`. This will display each time on the UI and may be you can add more logic based on the requriement.

Comment: that is for lists/arrays only